# Achartengine pan with animation

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to make the chart of achartengine to smoothly move while panning, and animate while I programmatically changes axis display range. Searching through the documents, there seems to be no provided function to achieve this. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can u add some image or code, what do u want to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely do this by changing the display area in a separate thread than the UI one, calling `mChartView.repaint()`, waiting for 20 ms or so then repeat the above.